# Who is/was the author of

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice, sentence-combination

if someone asks me or if there is a question in exams like "who is the author of Xxx book?" Should I answer in the past or present tense,like "Yyy is/was the author of Xxx book". I know the author is not alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would stick with the present tense. The author's death doesn't change the fact that they wrote the book.

Hence "Terry Pratchett *is* the author of *Mort*". (But "Terry wrote *Mort*" in the past tense.)

It is not a significant point, and using "was" doesn't affect understanding or sound unacceptable.

Comment: And the fact that the author is self-evidently *still alive* doesn't make [*I **was** the author of the book*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+was+the+author+of+the+book%22) in any way contradictory. Equally, there's nothing unusual about *I told them that although I **am** the author of the book, that doesn't mean I endorse everything the characters in it stand for.* It's all a matter of context and intended nuance.